# Correlation between node.js and number of cpu cores in GCP App engine flex

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

We are receiving data from GCP pub/sub to app engine.
However, as traffic increases, unacked messages in pub/sub are increasing. This seems to be due to the overload of the app engine, so I am trying to increase the specifications.
I know that node.js only uses a single core. At this time, I wonder if increasing the cpu core of the app engine will help?
(Assuming no clusters are used)

For testing, when I increased the number of cpu cores, it seemed to temporarily reduce unacked messages in pub/sub. I wonder if this is the effect of increasing the cpu core, or if it seemed to be temporarily reduced because of a new deployment.

Comment: Depends on your processing. CPU can improve the performances. You can also increase the number of instances in parallel.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thank you for you comment. :)  Could you give some more information how cpu can improve the performances on Node.js? I want to know how it works.

Comment: It's not related to NodeJS! If you have multiple CPU and your application support multi-threading, you can leverage multi-cpu on the same instance. But sometime it's complex to handle multi-cpu, that's why having multiple single-cpu-instances (scale out, horizontally) is also a great solution, especially to process PubSub messages.